# Can I call this C# class "immutable"?

Tags: c#, immutability, mutable

I need to make my *mutable* class *immutable*, now it looks like as following. However, still I'm not sure that I have a fully "immutable* class, and if it is, what kind of *immutability* this is called ?

```
public class B<C, M>
        where C : IComparable<C>
        where M : IMetaData
{

    internal B(char tau, M metadata, B<C, M> nextBlock)
    {
        if (tau == 'R') omega = 1;
        _lambda = new List<Lambda<C, M>>();
        _lambda.Add(new Lambda<C, M>(tau: tau, atI: metadata));
        foreach (var item in nextBlock.lambda)
            if (item.tau != 'L')
                _lambda.Add(new Lambda<C, M>(tau: 'M', atI: item.atI));
    }

    internal int omega { private set; get; }
    private List<Lambda<C, M>> _lambda { set; get; }
    internal ReadOnlyCollection<Lambda<C, M>> lambda { get { return _lambda.AsReadOnly(); } }



    internal B<C, M> Update(int Omega, char tau, M metadata)
    {
        B<C, M> newBlock = new B<C, M>();
        newBlock.omega = Omega;
        newBlock._lambda = new List<Lambda<C, M>>(this._lambda);
        newBlock._lambda.Add(new Lambda<C, M>(tau: tau, atI: metadata));
        return newBlock;
    }

    internal B<C, M> Update(Dictionary<uint, Lambda<C, M>> lambdas)
    {
        B<C, M> newBlock = new B<C, M>();
        newBlock.omega = this.omega;
        newBlock._lambda = new List<Lambda<C, M>>();
        foreach (var l in lambdas)
            newBlock._lambda.Add(new Lambda<C, M>(tau: l.Value.tau, atI: l.Value.atI));

        return newBlock;
    }
}

public class Lambda<C, M>
        where C : IComparable<C>
        where M : IMetaData
{
    internal Lambda(char tau, M atI)
    {
        this.tau = tau;
        this.atI = atI;
    }

    internal char tau { private set; get; }
    internal M atI { private set; get; }
}
```

Based on my application `B` needs to be changed from time to time; hence to keep the property of *immutability*, every update needs to be done throught `Update` function that returns a totally new `B`.

### Update

To shed a light on `IMetaData` that was cleverly spotted by *Jon Skeet* please consider following definitions:

```
public interface IMetaData
    {
        UInt32 hashKey { set; get; }
    }
```

and following class is passed as `M` to `B<C, M>`

```
public class MetaData : IMetaData
    {
        public UInt32 hashKey { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: It would certainly be more *obviously* immutable if all your fields were readonly (populated by constructors), and all the field types were also immutable (e.g. using the immutable collections library). Also, we don't know what your `Lambda` class looks like...

Comment: SInce you still could alter in-memory instance of that class with hacky reflection, we could argue against 'immutable', and try to invent a term like 'somewhat-write-protected' or 'not-public-writable'.. but that's a bit overdoing the thing. In common sense, I think immutable is OK, just keep in mind that if  private-reflection is in the game, then really nothing is safe. (and also remember private reflection can be disabled on whole platform like on WinPhone7).

Comment: @JonSkeet: We know `Lambda` class, it's at the bottom of the code and it has all bits `private` in a similar way.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Ah... I did look for it, but somehow failed to spot it.

Comment: does this question belong on codereview.stackexchange.com? not sure.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl You can always violate any type of "immutability" in C# through `unsafe` code.  Nothing is ever completely safe from truly evil code; it can only ever be safe from code that isn't actively trying to break it.

Comment: Now there's `IMetaData`... are there any mutable implementations of that? If you could create a `B<string, SomeMutableMetadata>` then it's not as immutable as it might be...

Comment: Thanks for comments, @quetzalcoatl how can I dodge reflection edits ?

Comment: @JonSkeet because of my bad formatting `Lambda` was as part of text rather than code; I fixed it.

Comment: Continuing, consider C++ or any other language with low level access. There, nothing is immutable in strict sense. With raw pointers you can overwrite anything (well if you have write access to that memory, but that's another thing). Looking this way, *immutability* is all about design and **predicted usage**, not about placing restrictions everywhere. Your design makes it relatively safe, so I'd vote for immutable. I'd do so even if you had some extra field like `object SecurityCookie` which would be readable and set after construction via 'Init' method, since the expected design/usage is so.

Comment: Is everything in this code a three letters thingy

Comment: Hamed - you can't. If reflection and its private-writing is available, then you can't do anything. If it's turned off, than you're lucky. I don't know if it is possible to force the platform to turn it off (there probably is a way for that) and I don't know if there's a way to do that only-for-your-class. If you succeeded, then it would probably work globally. There are some attributes like SecurityCritical that make some permission checks (reflection too), but with admin or System rights you could pass them anyways. There's always "something". Or check what Servy said about `unsafe`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No external code can ever observe any mutations of this type, which is enough for it to be considered "immutable" in common speach.  The only times it is ever mutated is during it's own constructor; it is never mutated once created, so no external entity could ever actually observe a mutation of the type.  This tends to be true of almost all types that are considered "immutable".

While the type does have the technical ability to mutate itself outside of its constructor in that it has both fields that are not `readonly` as well as a mutable `List`, it never actually performs any such mutations or exposes any means of mutating the data.

Comment: `List<...> _lambda` worries me; as you mentioned it's not really `immutable` but rather *not-public-writable* as *quetzalcoatl* mentioned. Do you have any suggestions for improving it ... giving rise to **immutable** list ?

Comment: @Hamed Don't store a mutable list at all; store a read only list, and create/assign the read only list in the constructor.

Comment: @Hamed - Keep in mind that even the 'readonly' list is only readonly by name and design. Internally it will use some List or Array that are mutable. So if someone hacks into your code and gets their hands on that ReadOnlyList you used, then likewise they will hack in to that class and get to the raw mutable storage thingy. Really, I think you shouldn't try to place your wards here. If you want to prevent a professional from performing mutations, then, well, the best way is to leave a comment "don't do that, because XYZ". Nonprofessionals will be bounced by internal/private API as you have it.

Comment: based on comments, to me seems like there is no way to make this class *immutable* in it's true sense! am I right ?

Comment: @Hamed You'll have to define the term yourself if you want us to determine if it meets your own definition.  I defined the commonly used definition of the term in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of immutable class types achieve their immutability by encapsulating data in an object of mutable class type but ensuring that no reference to that object will ever be exposed to code that might mutate it.  Given that .NET does not have any immutable array types other than `String`, such an approach is often the only practical way for a variable-sized collection to offer efficient random access.  Types which do not need to offer efficient random access could use more "deeply immutable" means of storing data such as linked lists or trees that store everything in `readonly` fields, but in practice if there is no possible execution sequence via which a particular object instance could be mutated, then that particular instance may be legitimately described as "immutable" even if its class would allow the instance to be mutated by anyone with a reference to it.

With regard to whether an interface-type reference may be regarded as identifying an immutable object, that would depend upon whether there is a contract in either the interface itself, or in the means by which the reference was supplied, which would specify either that all legitimate implementations of that interface will be immutable, that the particular instance identified by the reference will be immutable, or (if the code holding the reference never exposes it to outside code) that the instance will never be exposed to code that might mutate it.  If the interface promises immutability, then code receiving a reference from outside code could use it directly; otherwise, it would have to receive the reference from code that promises that there won't be any "unsheltered" references to it.  One possible pattern would be to have an interface offer an `AsReadableSnaphot` method which would guarantee to return an object encapsulating the state of the object upon this it is invoked, and would promise that no outside reference existed which would mutate the object in question; an immutable class might implement such a method to simply return itself, while a mutable one might implement it to return a clone of itself).  If instances of the class might be big, it might be desirable to have `AsReadableSnapshot` create an immutable class instance (so that calling `AsReadableSnapshot` wouldn't have to make yet another copy of the data therein) but if they will always be small, having the returned object be of a mutable type shouldn't be a problem.